# Convert RGB to Gray with my own formula in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, android

I'd like to convert a RGB image to Gray like this function does :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
```

But openCV uses a specific formula (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B I think ?), and I'd like to use min(R,G,B) instead.

Is there a performance-efficient way to do that ? (This is OpenCV for android, so with Java)

**EDIT :**

Here is the profiling, which I definitely should have done earlier :

Base application capturing the camera runs at 12 FPS

- with OpenCV's cvtColor() : 12 FPS (speed difference is insignificant)
- with Mark Miller's answer : 1.5 FPS
- with Mark Miller's answer and Miki's optimization (get the data pointer once) : 7 FPS

That may look incredible but just that little function costs half the FPS. The device can yet run very complicated stuff like ORB at decent rates (3-4 FPS), and all O(n) C++ routines without FPS difference. Also just Miki's  "trick" makes the function 10x faster.

Comment: you need to convert from RGB to Grayscale???

Comment: yes, but I'd also like a way to tell openCV the formula it has to use when converting

Comment: for that have you import that openCV library to your project?

Comment: "Is there a performance-efficient way to do that ?" - No. you cannot do it from java, and even using jni it will be a lot of hard work.

Comment: @Parth Bhayani No, my whole project is based on openCV. (I added "openCV" in the title, sorry)

Comment: But if your project is based on openCV for that you need to add that library into your workspace and also adding to your project as well.

Comment: Yes I did it and it works well for my project.

Comment: Really, @berak? `split` and two calls to `min` won't do it? I'll take your word on that since I haven't used OpenCV in Java, only in C++.

Comment: Well, if you're talking about performance, probably java isn't the best choice. However, what's your reference image? how long does it take CvtColor? And with naive implementation of your modified functon (which you should post, btw)? Without such information your question is meaningless.

Comment: I'm just asking what's the proper way to do something (because it looked probable to me that openCV allowed it directly). How is that meaningless ?

Comment: I believe Miki is focusing on the "performance-efficient" side. Without having a baseline of what counts as efficient, the question can't be answered, because there's a spectrum of answers at different levels on the readable vs. fast scale. I gave the simplest answer because most of the time, rule #1 of optimization holds true.

Comment: Yes, I meant "more efficient than writing the loops in Java", which I assumed to be very slow compared to calling a native method (but in fact, I may be wrong ?). Thank you for the answer and the comments also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-built way to give OpenCV an arbitrary function for conversion to grayscale. The remaining option is using the RGB channels themselves.

```
for (int x = 0; x < mRgba.cols(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < mRgba.rows(); y++)
    {
        double[] rgb = mRgba.get(x, y);
        mGray.put(x, y, Math.min(rgb[0], Math.min(rgb[1], rgb[2])));
    }
}
```

As you have mentioned, it may be too slow, especially with large images and the branching that comes from if-statements. However, there are three rules of optimization: (1) Don't do it, (2) Don't do it yet, and (3) Profile first. Simply put, try the easy-to-code version first, then once you know for a fact this section is the slow section [i.e, by running it and timing it], change the code to be more efficient.

Comment: you got my -1 for the code, but +1 for the optimization considerations. So 0 :D

Comment: @Miki What's bad about the code? It's in Java, and it's slow? Edits and comments are welcome.

Comment: well, at least invert inner and outer loop (so you can access data sequentially in ram and optimize cache), I don't know much of Java way of doing things, but if it was in C++, I'd take the pointer of each row and work on pointers. I don't know the java way of doing so (that's why I haven't posted my answer). I strongly agree with you on optimization stuff, as you can see from my comment to the question.

Comment: ah, this should do the trick to get the pointer to data `Mat fv; ... ; int size = (int) fv.total() * fv.channels();   double[] buff = new double[size];     fv.get(0, 0, buff);`

Comment: @Miki this "trick" is amazing, makes the function at least 10x times faster. Finally I didn't use min because it was still too slow, but applying this trick in other parts of my code made them a lot faster

Comment: @Saiph invert also the for loops, you should get a great speedup.